# Valgrind pthread_create woes

Tags: c

On running `valgrind --leak_check=yes` with my executable file I get the following errors.

```
==17325== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 17 of 21
==17325==    at 0x4004C42: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:418)
==17325==    by 0xCC5CA9: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib/ld-2.5.so)
==17325==    by 0xD0BF5C: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==17325==    by 0x8049334: init (prog.c:238)
==17325==    by 0x804C94F: main (prog.c:163)
```

It is pointing to my pthread_create call. I called pthread_detach after creating the thread. I don't want to call pthread_join. I searched about this and found many people faced the same issue but I couldn't find the exact reason for this. Is this because of the behavior of pthread library? Can someone please provide good links which talk about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `pthread_join` on a detached thread is illegal. Don't detach the thread if you want to be able to join it.

Comment: @I don't want to join the thread. I read somewhere that calling pthread_join will solve the problem and give no errors in valgrind. I called pthread_detach for the same reason.